# How can i transform this scala function in order to be optimized

Tags: scala, tail-recursion, tail-call-optimization

Code to determine the lat element of a list, using pattern matching:

```
  @tailrec
  def last_rec[A](list : List[A]) : A = {
    list match {
      case (x :: Nil) => x
      case (_ :: xs) => last_rec(xs)
      case Nil => throw new NoSuchElementException
    }
  }
```

I want to compile the code, I am getting "yelled" by the compiler:

```
PS D:\workspace\scala\P99> scalac .\P01.scala
.\P01.scala:18: error: could not optimize @tailrec annotated method last2: it contains a recursive call not in tail position
      case Nil => throw new NoSuchElementException
                        ^
one error found
```

If I remove the @tailrec annotation - the code compiles . How can I modify the code in order to do the tail rec optimization ?

Comment: I think there should be one more compiler error: `last is undefined`

Comment: I'm confused: your method isn't even *recursive*, so why would you even *expect* it to be tail-recursive?

Comment: Also: the error message you provided doesn't match up with the code you posted. The error message refers to a line number 18, which doesn't exist and it refers to a method `last2` which doesn't exist, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got a typo their. Your method is called `last_rec` and you are calling `last` which is clearly undefined. So just rename it to `last`. And by the way you should return `Option[A]` instead of `A`. That way you can return `None` when nothing is found instead of throwing the ugly `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: IMO an `Option` or `Either` is inappropriate here and an Exception should be thrown if you try to pass the function an empty list. Imagine if the real `last`, or the `head` and `tail` operations on `List` all had to return an `Option` in case they're empty!

Answer (score 1):

After removing the typo and adding agilesteel's suggestion:

```
@tailrec
def last_rec[A](list : List[A]) : Option[A] = {
  list match {
   case (x :: Nil) => Some(x)     
   case Nil => None
   case (_ :: xs) => last_rec(xs)
 }
}
```

Comment: `Option(x)` should be `Some(x)` though ;)

Comment: Well, `Option(x)` would give you `None` in case the last element is `null`. That might not be the desired behavior, but it's worth noting that it is a possible way to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would do what agilesteel suggested.

However, if you really wanted to throw an exception (in another different use case), you could do it in a statically typed way:

```
@tailrec
  def last_rec[A](list : List[A]) : Either[NoSuchElementException,A] = {
    list match {
      case (x :: Nil) => Right(x)
      case (_ :: xs) => last_rec(xs)
      case Nil => Left(new NoSuchElementException)
    }
  }
```

where later you could:

```
last_rec(Nil) match {
 case Right(s) => println("Got a value")
 case Left(e) => println("Got an exception")
}
```

Comment: It's conventional to have exception on the `Left` in such cases (see, e.g., `Catch.either`).